# DllNotFoundException even though the DLL is there?

Tags: c#, dll, uwp, dllimport

I worked on an audio visualization library that wraps around a dll (written in c), and as the library was tested, worked, and finished, I wanted to include the library in my main project. To my surprise, however, a DllNotFoundException occurred in my main project.
For some reason the left project fails, the right works fine:

[image: Projects]

Both Applications are UWP, both are 32bit, both invoke the library the same way, jet one of them fails, the other doesnt???

The dll has no other dependencies and does not mangle the function names.
It says that the dll was not found even though the dll is on the same location on both projects.
[image: dll is in the right directory]

I just  cant figure out, why it doesnt work in one project, but it does work in another...

Comment: Either the DLL, or one of its dependencies cannot be found

Comment: Is the DLL using the correct CPU architecture?